# Change function parameter based select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using moment + jquery to list year calendar weeks and items, but I've hardcoded this year, so now Current code for hardcoded calendar year works, so now I'm trying to make select list for the years, so user can change 2020, 2021, 2022 years and this showCalendar(2020); is going to update, (I just need a three next years so..), but I'm not quite sure how I can change this showCalendar(); parameter with dropdown select list? Thanks for the help, if someone have any time to check this :)

This is what print calendar based on year that we have hardcoded

```
function setup(){

    showCalendar(2020); // When change this in 2021 it works.

}


function showCalendar(year){

// all (week numbers, days etc...)
```

In web-view:

```
<select id="Year" class="">
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna get the `<select>` option, so something like this would work

```js
let sel = document.getElementById('Year');
let lastValue = sel.value
function setup(){

    showCalendar(sel.value); // 2020, 2021, or whatever is selected

}

setInterval(() => {
    if(sel.value !== lastValue) setup();
    //you wanna call setUp everytime the value change
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. First I got setUp is not defined, but then I change it: setup, and no errors showing up. Only problem is that it now get first value of <select> option, but when I pick up example: 2021 it shows empty.

Comment: yes I had a typo my bad, you need to add the `showCalendar` function in there too. It should work fine